# How can I use a dynamic collection name in a JSP loop?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

HI,

I need to be able to do something like this (of course this doesn't work:

```
  <c:forEach var="column" items="${model.${listName}.enabledColumns}">
    ${column.name}
  </c:forEach>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
${requestScope[listName].eanbledColumns}
```

or, if your `model` is actually a map within the request, then:

```
${model[listName].enabledColumns}
```

Comment: The listName is a param passed to this .tag as a String with the actual list name.

Comment: @goe - what is "model" ? is listName param or attribute? Give more information.

Answer (score 1):

If the `${listName}` in this context is a property of your `model` (something you would normally access as `model.getListNameX()`, this would only be possible with reflection, and the Expression Language has no support for that.

But it looks like a refactoring of your class would be more helpful. If you want to iterate through those `${listName}`s (assuming these are currently properties of your `model`) , why don't you just keep a map with enum constants as keys and those objects you want to reference via `${listName}` as values ? (an `EnumMap` would be helpful here).

Then, you can set the `Enum.values()` as a request attribute, iterate through them as `listName` and have:

```
${model.lists[listName].enabledColumns}
```